# How to extract gradient css code from an AI design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, illustrator-scripting

I have been given a design for a web page made in Adobe Illustrator. What I would like to do is to convert the gradient inside the design to css code to use for the web page implementation. How can this be done in illustrator/Photoshop cc (2017)

Comment: Can't you just look at the values and copy them?

Answer (score 2):

I had this script lying around, use at own risk:

```
#target illustrator

(function() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var str = '';
    for(var i=0; i < doc .gradients.length; i++) {
        var gradient = app.activeDocument.gradients[i];
        str += gradient.name+ ':\n';
        str+= gradientStopsToStr(gradient);
     }
     showCopyableDialog(str);
})();

function showCopyableDialog(str){
    var w = new Window ('dialog');
    p1 = w.add ('edittext {preferredSize: [600, 400], properties: {multiline: true}}');
    p1.text = str;
    w.show ();
}

function gradientStopsToStr(gradient){

    if (gradient.type == GradientType.LINEAR)
        retval = '     linear-gradient(0deg, ';
    else 
       retval = '    radial-gradient(Circle, ';
    for(var i=0; i < gradient.gradientStops.length-1; i++) {
        var stop = gradient.gradientStops[i];
        retval += rgbaToStr(stop.color, stop.opacity)+ ' '+stop.rampPoint+'%, ';
    }
    var stop = gradient.gradientStops[gradient.gradientStops.length-1];
    retval += rgbaToStr(stop.color, stop.opacity)+ ' '+stop.rampPoint+'%)';
    retval += '\n'
    return retval;
 }

function rgbaToStr(color, opacity){
    retval = ' rgba(';
    if(color instanceof RGBColor){
       retval +=  color.red
                +   ', ' + color.green
                +   ', ' + color.blue
                +   ', '+ opacity/100 +')';
     }
    return retval;
 }
```

The script iterates all swatches (yes that means all used gradients need to be added to swatches) and generates css for each. Then pops up a windows with a dialog you can copy paste somewhere for further refinement